# Escape characters in JQuery containing Java Codes

Tags: java, jquery, html

I'm working with JSP pages, and I need to append some HTML and Java codes inside a DIV, I only remember that I should escape " like this \", but I don't know about the other characters and I don't know if all non-letter characters should be escaped, here is the String.

```
 String s ="<% ResultSet joinedRooms = myJavaDB.updateJoinedRooms(loginBean.getId());

 while(joinedRooms.next()){%> <div id="<%=joinedRooms.getString(1)%>" class="chatRoom">

<div class="chatRoomName"><%=myJavaDB.getRoomName(joinedRooms.getInt(1))%></div></div><% } %>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to roll your own, take a look at Apache Commons [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

I cannot import those 2 packages, should I download them or what ?

Comment: Yes, download the precompiled jars and include them in your class path, or download the source files.  It is more usual to use the jar files.

Comment: I downloaded the package but can you please tell me how to "include them in my class path" ?